# make div inside include file unaffected by its parent

Tags: javascript, php, css, include

I'm currently trying to build a slideshow for images, which I want to be reusable easily. Meaning i want all the html and php code inside one include file.

So now I'm facing the problem that the slideshow div has to be position: fixed; but the file has to be included inside a container for the preview images.

Is there any way in html/css/javascript/php to make the diashow div unaffected by all its parent divs in means of position, so that it can be a proper fixed element?

so here is a simple example. This is my main file:

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
       <?php include('slideshow.php'); ?>
   </div>
</body>
```

This is my slideshow.php file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="slideshow.css">

<div class="slideshow"><img /><img /></div>
<div class="preview-images"><img /><img /></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="slideshow.js"></script>
```

The preview images are supposed to be inside the container but the slideshow has to be fixed to the window, when activated. I want it to behave like it was at the top inside the body tag, so it can overlap everything else.

Comment: Can you please include an example of your markup?

Comment: I guess you're looking for [!important](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: Not sure how !important is supposed to help me.. I added an example to hopefully clarify my problem.